# Is acrylic OK for children's toys under EU regulations?

Tags: materials, regulations

I am developing a toy for 2-6-year old children with parts in acrylic ( Poly(methyl methacrylate)). I searched [Toy Safety Directive 2009/48/EC](http://ec.europa.eu/DocsRoom/documents/4208/attachments/1/translations/en/renditions/native) and [Regulation 1907/2006 REACH](https://osha.europa.eu/en/legislation/directives/regulation-ec-no-1907-2006-of-the-european-parliament-and-of-the-council) for mentions of perspex or acrylic and found nothing.

Is acrylic OK for children's toys under EU regulations?

Comment: It is used for child safety equipment ("unbreakable" mirrors etc) as well as stair gates, play pens, and so on. I would think the biggest issue would be small parts which could be swallowed, but that is independent of the material.

Comment: It is best not to call the material perspex, just acrylic or PMMA. Because perspex is a trade name, and the owner of the name may change composition of the material at their will, which may lead to mistakes down the line.

Comment: @joojaa: Good point, I edited the question and will remove this comment in a few days.

Comment: Note, PMMA is also used as the acronym for a designer drug (para-Methoxy-N-methylamphetamine), also known as MDMA or Ecstasy, which has nothing to do with "Perspex". I recommend using "acrylic" if you want to avoid a trade name. Perspex is just one of a number of trade names for the same material, such as Plexiglass, Lucite, etc.